# What would be the most practical way to implement a universal disassembler?

Tags: entropy

Let's say I wanted to create a "universal disassembler", which I define as a machine into which you can insert any (reasonably-sized) object into the input end, and the object is reduced to its component elements which are then sorted and placed into 118 separate bins at the output side, ready to be used as raw materials.

Is there a known physical process that could be used to implement this?  I imagine that doing this would require a lot of energy since it is working against entropy, but let's assume that there is a lot of energy available.

Comment: What you want is basically a mass spectrometer.

Comment: You're describing a laborer at a junk yard...

Comment: @MaxW maybe, but most laborers don't have fingers small enough to e.g. separate iron oxide back into iron and oxygen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As probably_someone pointed out, this is basically a mass spectrometer. Still, "most practical" way is tricky to define.

By breaking the bonds between atoms they can be separated (at an energy cost $< 1080$ kJ/mol per bond) and then recombined (at an energy gain or cost depending on the new enthalpy of the molecule). If we had proper nanotechnology we might be able to do this and sorting with a minimum of fuss, but most actual schemes right now are based on strong heating.

In [plasma arc recycling](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/plasma-arc-recycling.html) waste is heated into monoatomic gas that is then allowed to recombine. This might be combined with a mass spectrometer/plasma separation method where atoms are ionized into a plasma, and separated by the different mass-charge ratios of their nuclei as they move through a magnetic field. [This has been proposed for rare earths and nuclear waste recycling](http://ocs.ciemat.es/EPS2018PAP/pdf/P2.3013.pdf), as well as for [noble metals](http://www.ispc-conference.org/ispcproc/papers/25.pdf). Doing it so the elements all have different mass-charge ratios so they neatly separate in the field may turn out to be tricky; most existing schemes merely gather groups of elements for further separation steps.

One can presumably also separate elements using selective laser ionization, since it works for isotope separations.

[The minimal possible entropy cost of extracting all the elements](http://web.mit.edu/ebm/www/Publications/RECYCLE%20IEEE%202008.pdf), having mole fractions $x_i$ is $$W_{allextract} = -TR \sum_i x_i \ln(x_i).$$ Note that it could be far more efficient if done at a low temperature $T$.

(See also [Feasability of plasma based garbage recycling into pure constituent elements](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/120206/feasability-of-plasma-based-garbage-recycling-into-pure-constituent-elements))